# Beamer: change size of enumerate bullet

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I'm trying to modify the size of `enumerate` bullets in `beamer`. This is my code:

```
\section{References}
\begin{frame}
\huge{
\begin{enumerate}[5]
\item References
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{frame}
```

This is the result:
[image]

Text is resized, but not the bullet. I tried `\item[\huge$\bullet$]`, but then enumeration is lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the font size of the square enumerate item via `\setbeamerfont{item projected}{size=\huge}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\begin{document}
\section{References}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\huge}
\setbeamerfont{item projected}{size=\huge}
\begin{enumerate}
\addtocounter{enumi}{4}
\item References
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

From the looks of it, you are trying to manually create some kind of section page? If yes, it would be easier to let beamer do this for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}{
    \huge
    {\color{structure.fg}
    \vrule width2.25ex height1.85ex depth.4ex}%
    \hskip-2.25ex%
    \hbox to2.25ex{%
      \hfil%
      \color{white}\insertsectionnumber%
      \hfil}%
    \space
    \insertsectionhead
}

\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}
\sectionpage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{References}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```